# creating groups for decimal values using crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I have a parameter that ranges from (0-1.0). I am trying to create a `dc.js` bar chart, so that there are 10 bars representing (0-0.1)  (0.1-0.2) and so on.
I am using `crossfilter.js` to create dimension and group data, but it does not seem to create groups as required.

I tried the following code

```
var fluctuation = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.value;
});

var fluctuationGroup = fluctuation.group(function(d){
  return Math.round(d*10)/10;
});
```

I also tried doing it another way.

```
var fluctuation = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return Math.round(d.value*10)/10;
});

var fluctuationGroup = fluctuation.group(function(d){
  return d;
});
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: What happens in each situation? Just off the top of my head, it looks like both should more or less work, though I would use Math.floor() to get the ranges you want, instead of Math.round().

Comment: Just edited the post and added a picture of how it looks like

Comment: Looks like it could be OK, not knowing your data. What does fluctuationGroup.all() give you? And what do you expect to get? What does your data look like? I'd recommend putting it in a working example on jsfiddle or jsbin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry folks, it was not a crossfilter problem. It was a rendering problem.

I was not using 
xUnits(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]))  with the chart.

Please suggest if I should delete this question ? Or update it ??

Comment: Accept your own answer and keep the question here